# Very Strict Rule with Regex Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I have something like this:

```
<script>
    function myfunction(){
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editable.getData();
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is, if data does not match this:

```
<h2>Any text allowed here but only text<h2>
```

I want to warn the user. 
How can I do this?
Thank you..

I will edit my question, I guess it was not clear enough..

the data variable is read from somewhere. It is not important.
When a button is clicked, this function is called.
The data variable ( which is a string ) can only be something like this:

```
<h2> ANY TEXT HERE </h2>
```

So these are not allowed:

```
Anytext
<h1>any text</h1>
<a href=..>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I can't understand the question =/. So do you want user input data to be "<h2>Any text allowed here but only text<h2>"?

Comment: So it should only match a `h2` element without any attributes, which contains only plain text?

Comment: @Zeta Yes. Correct. I have also edited my quetsion.

Comment: Still, you have to define what you mean by "text". Only ascii letters? Letters + blanks? Digits?

Comment: @thg435 Yes sorry. Letters from a to z and numbers. Of course blanks..

Comment: Ok, then `/^<h2>[A-Z0-9 ]+<\/h2>$/i`

Comment: @thg435 Thank you. How can I also make sure that there is at least one character between h2 tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1:

```
var pattern = /<h2>[^\d]+<\/h2>/;
console.log(pattern.test('<h2>asf</h2>'));
```

This will prevent any numbers but accept only plain letters.

Version 2:

```
var pattern = /<h2>[A-Za-z]+<\/h2>/;
    console.log(pattern.test('<h2>asf</h2>'));
```

Which will accept A-Za-z only inbetween  tags

Version 3:

```
   var pattern = /<h2>[^\<\>\/\d]+<\/h2>/;
    console.log(pattern.test('<h2>asf?1.,</h2>'));
```

This will accept anything except numbers and  to prevent any closing tags

Comment: Won't it suffice to just exclude the starting bracket of the closing tag? `/<h2>[^<]+<\/h2>/` **Edit:** Never mind, the OP has commented that only alphanumeric characters and spaces are allowed. Use a positive match: `/<h2>(?:\w|\s)+<\/h2>/`

Comment: Can you make it allowing digits and blank spaces as well?

Comment: Also, when you just press space a few times, the text is accepted. How can I be sure that there is some text ( at least 1 character ) between h2 tags?

Comment: You must trim string first. Using String.trim(theString); It will remove all blank spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Use your browser's HTML parsing capabilities instead of RegEx. Just set the specified string as some element's `.innerHTML` then check the children using DOM functions:

```
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = "<h2>Any text allowed here but only text</h2>";
if (
    temp.childNodes.length == 1 &&            // has only one child
    temp.firstChild.tagName == "H2" &&        // that child is a H2
    temp.firstChild.childNodes.length == 1 && // H2 as only one child
    temp.firstChild.firstChild.nodeType == 3  // that child a Node.TEXT_NODE
) {
    alert("valid");
} else {
    alert("invalid");
}
```

Comment: +1, however, `Node.TEXT_NODE` instead of `3` would make things a little bit more clear for OP.

Comment: Not only will this more than likely be slower than a regular expression (HTML parsing + DOM manipulation), it might even open some cross-script vulnerabilities when the input comes from an untrusted source.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: I agree with you about the being slow part. But I don't understand the cross-script part. Do you have an example why a regex solution would be _safer_ than this?

Comment: `<script>` elements don't execute using innerHTML... however there are still other ways. I recommend `var temp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("").body` and use the div as fallback for IE. The created HTML document is safe to use unless you replace the active document with the created one.